# Capture window.postMessage in Swift WKWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, native, wkwebview

I am developing a swift ios app that uses `WKWebView` to load up an ecommerce site.
When a user purchases a product here, the checkout page allows the user to pay in cryptocurrency.

When the user clicks "Open in Wallet", the site shoots off a 
`window.postMessage(paymentData)` 
where payment data is a js object with a bitcoin url in it.

I am using a `WKUserScript` with `WKWebConfiguration` to inject a script that listens for a window message and then fires off data to my `webkit.messageHandler.`

```
let source = """
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) { window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(e.data)) } )
    """
```

Unfortunately this code never triggers.

When I use chrome or safari devtools to inject the same javascript, it works just fine.

I have scoured stack overflow to see if there is a special condition for `window.postMessage` in `WKWebView` but have had no luck thus far.

Is it possible to capture a `window.postMessage()` event and pipe the event data back to my ios app?

Thanks in advance!!!!
Here is my existing code.

```
  let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let source = """
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) { window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(e.data)) } )
    """
    let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
    userContentController.addUserScript(script)

    userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
    webConfiguration.userContentController = userContentController
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

```
 func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("message body: \(message.body)")
    print("message frameInfo: \(message.frameInfo)")
  }
```

Comment: Did you solve it? Consider upvoting / accepting / interacting with answers to generate valuable knowledge to the website. It's not a good practice to ask a question and never return to it.

Comment: Hi @GustavoVollbrecht. I was on vacation and hoping I might get a few more answers.  Thank you for your contribution but unfortunately we are still unable to catch the window.postMessage event. What is odd is we can capture any other event such as onClick.   

it is specifically ```window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), '*');```  that we cannot capture.
If you were interested, I could share the url of the site with you. 
Thanks again. I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @MFD3000, did you solve it? I ran into this as well. I got it working after changing to   `injectionTime: .atDocumentStart`

Comment: @JannoTeelem: My code now also works if I use `atDocumentStart`. It would be interesting if this answer would work for the OP.

Comment: @MFD3000 I am facing similar issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not the lead on that particular issue.  Lead opted to opted to go for a working solution at the expense of a good ux.
If anyone has luck with any provided solutions here, Id gladly mark it solved.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible. You also need to set `javascriptEnabled = true`

```
self.webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

You can also configure the listener like this:

```
self.webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "iosListener")
```

And make sure you're applying both commands before

```
self.webView.load(/*some request*/)
```

You can make a simple test after the page `didFinish` loading with:

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage('test');", completionHandler: { (result, err) in
    if (err != nil) {
        // show error feedback to user.
    }
})
```

Another advice is to always have `;` at the end of commands on javascript code when interacting with `webView` as some can rely on standard javascript.

```
let source = """
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(e.data));
    });
    """
```

---

**Note:** I'd also suggest to have the `webView` as a class variable instead of a method variable, you're probably creating it on `viewDidLoad()`, I'd suggest that you move the variable to your class.

`var webView: WKWebView!`

Comment: @SmarterSusheel on his next line, WKUserScript init

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht I need to listen on payment response from third party in iOS app, and I am using above message eventlistener and userContentController method is not hitting after receiving response from third party, whereas other listeners are working for example, focus, click are hitting userContentController. Please advice

Comment: @subha Please post your own question with lots of details.