# How to listen window.postMessage("") from webpage from iOS Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode

I am creating an eCommerce app, in which placing order and payment will be carried out by webview. Once order placed webpage sends message in

`window.postMessage("message")`

From WKWebview, I want to listen this and capture the message from this callback and proceed further from iOS App. Help me to solve this.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692368/capture-window-postmessage-in-swift-wkwebview) topic can help you

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Yes this is working fine. why cannot we read data from window.postMessage("message")?, do we need to create script like          window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(e.data)); ?

Comment: Is it mandate to post the message with  webkit and custom handler like window.webkit.messageHandlers.iosListener.postMessage()

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t tell you, but I recommend clarifying your question at the topic that I showed.