# How can I inject JavaScript into WKWebView in Swift in a timely manner?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, http, post

I am trying to solve Javascript injection issue, but I am pretty new to Swift and don't really know where to look for answers. WKWebView allows injecting javascript only at the beginning or the end of the document. Is it possible to do it let's say every 10 sec?

What I'm trying to do is to send gps speed via POST requests that share the same header, and I was successful, but I am limited only to the beginning or end injections. If that is not possible, is there a way to fire the Javascript and pass parameters to it, or somehow use DOM to communicate with the script?

Comment: Use `webView(_:didFinish:)`?

Comment: I need to constantly be injecting scripts though.

Comment: Does `WKWebView.evaluateJavascript` not accomplish this? You can start a `Timer` in your swift code which can fire every X seconds to run some javascript. It's also possible to work with webkit event handlers, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692368/capture-window-postmessage-in-swift-wkwebview describes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.